# SAS Programming: where condition using y1 to y20 variables

Tags: sas, where-clause, subset

I would like to create a subset of sas table that contains variables y1 to y10, where y1 to y10 are greater then 0,

```
   data work.dt;
   set work.x;

   **where y1 to y10> 0;**

   run;
```

Is there a shortcut for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use it this way, with `if`:

```
data work.dt;
set work.x;
if min(of y1-y10) > 0;
run;
```

Or you can write it out.  `where` uses mostly SQL language elements and doesn't get to use all of the SAS language elements like variable lists in their complete form.